# Apache truncates HTTP header

Tags: apache, http

I'm experimenting a very strange issue: using apache-2.2.25 on an Arch Linux server I get a truncated HTTP header in response, but only under windows machines.

I left untouched the httpd.conf file and I have created a file /srv/http/index.html with inside `Hello`.

With a web browser on a Linux machine I get correctly visualized the hello page, but under Windows I get

```
.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2013 08:44:28 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Nov 2013 08:15:09 GMT ETag: "27c-a-4eb32cbf8b950" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 10 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Hello
```

It seems that the http header is truncated for the first characters (`HTTP/1`).

Have you got any advices?

Comment: Do you have certain exoctic Apache modules? Do you have it with any Apache version? Is this a clean install or did you change something that made it cease working? Is there a firewall or proxy server on server or client? What if you disable that? Do you have it with any browser on any Windows machine? What does a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) say? Does the response not contain any newlines? Is there anything useful in Apache's logs?

Comment: I have the basic installation of apache,no extra modules installed. I have tested only with this version beacuase is the latest. As I stated before is a clean install and in the post I wrote that http.conf is untouched.I don't know about any server proxy or firewall because the machine is in a cloud and I cannot modify it. No firewalls or proxy on client. Yes, I have it on any Windows machine with the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE.I've never used Fiddler but only firebug.The response is what I reported in the post:no newlines but missing characters. Nothing reported in Apache logs.